# How to make smooth transition for switchable scatterplot?

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I need help with this code that i just code, i make a switchable chart. But there is problem when switch/update the chart. they keep stack and stack from the previous chart. Please help me find the error.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]).nice()

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);



function update(selectedVar) {

  d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/iris.csv", function(data) {

    minLatitude = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d.Sepal_Length);
    })
    maxLatitude = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d.Sepal_Length);
    })
    x.domain([minLatitude, maxLatitude]);
    var xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    xAxis.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);
    minH = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    maxH = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    y.domain([minH, maxH]).nice()
    var yAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "myYaxis")

    yAxis.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 13100000])
      .range([6, width]);

    var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var u = svg.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)

    u.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .merge(u)
      .transition(100)
      .attr("class", "bubbles")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.Sepal_Length);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return rScale(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return myColor(d.Species);
      })
  });
};
update('Petal_Width')
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="update('Petal_Width')">Petal_Width</button>
<button onclick="update('Sepal_Width')">Sepal_Width</button>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

so the code above, i switch the variable of y-axis only and keep x-axis. its work i think, but the previous variable plot still there with new variable plot. So the chart keep stack infinitely.

Comment: Can you reproduce the example in a JSFiddle, Codesandbox or use the Stackoverflow snippets?

Comment: sorry. done reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why the circles were constantly appended was because you used the invalid selector `dot`. You need to use the syntax you might know from `document.querySelectorAll`, jQuery, or plain old CSS. To select the `circle`s with class `bubble`, use `circle` or `.bubble`, not `dot`.

But besides that, you were doing a lot of unnecessary stuff in your code, like adding a new axis every time you updated the chart, without removing the old one. I've attempted to add and explain some best practices here. If you have any questions, let me know.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]).nice()

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 13100000])
  .range([6, width]);

var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

// Split your code into stuff you only need to do once and stuff you need to
// do on every update. `.append()` is generally only required once, except with
// `.enter()`.
var data;

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/iris.csv", function(csvData) {
  csvData.forEach(function(d) {
    // You help yourself a lot by just doing this once
    d.Sepal_Length = parseFloat(d.Sepal_Length);
    d.Petal_Width = parseFloat(d.Petal_Width);
  });
  data = csvData;
  
  draw();
});

var xAxis, yAxis;

function draw() {
  // This is generally something you do once
  xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  yAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "myYaxis")

  update('Petal_Width');
}

function update(selectedVar) {
  // Use `d3.extent`. It does exactly what you want,
  // by calculating [min, max] from an array but saves you time.
  // This can technically be in `draw()` because it does the same
  // thing each time, but that's only in this case. Normally,
  // you want it in `update()`
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Sepal_Length; }));

  xAxis.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[selectedVar]; })).nice();

  yAxis.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Your selector needs to be valid here. Use `circle` or `.bubbles`.
  // `dot` is always invalid
  var u = svg.selectAll(".bubbles")
    .data(data)

  u.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .merge(u)
    .transition(100)
    .attr("class", "bubbles")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.Sepal_Length);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return rScale(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return myColor(d.Species);
    });
  
  u.exit().remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="update('Petal_Width')">Petal_Width</button>
<button onclick="update('Sepal_Width')">Sepal_Width</button>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: oh I see. thanks for remind me. As a newbie also student, I have learned a lot from you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]).nice()

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);


function update(selectedVar) {
  const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg").attr('class', 'svg-container')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
  d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/iris.csv", function(data) {

    minLatitude = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d.Sepal_Length);
    })
    maxLatitude = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d.Sepal_Length);
    })
    x.domain([minLatitude, maxLatitude]);
    var xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    xAxis.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);
    minH = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    maxH = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return parseFloat(d[selectedVar]);
    })
    y.domain([minH, maxH]).nice()
    var yAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "myYaxis")

    yAxis.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 13100000])
      .range([6, width]);

    var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var u = svg.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)

    u.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .merge(u)
      .transition(100)
      .attr("class", "bubbles")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.Sepal_Length);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return rScale(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d[selectedVar]);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return myColor(d.Species);
      })
  });
};
update('Petal_Width')
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="d3.select('.svg-container').remove(); update('Petal_Width')">Petal_Width</button>
<button onclick="d3.select('.svg-container').remove(); update('Sepal_Width')">Sepal_Width</button>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Full-code answers with no explanation are generally not considered very helpful. You'll be more helpful and will get more appreciation for well-founded answers that can help the OP and any other user with the same problem.